# Uncaught Reference Error: google is not defined (Google Maps JavaScript API usage with client-side webpart project

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, sharepoint-online

For a bit of context, I'm building a client-side webpart (SharePoint Framework) to calculate routes given waypoints specified by the user. The project has been scaffolded using React and TypeScript.

So far, I've managed to display the map using Tom Chen's react-google-maps. I've used the `withScriptjs` method to asynchronously load Google Maps API V3 and it's working fine i.e. the map shows up.
Now the problem is I can't get hold of the 'google' object needed to access the Directions Service (which will be used to calculate and render routes on the map)

Here on StackOverflow, similar answers have been asked and from the answers, I get that the problem comes from the fact that the code using the object

```
public componentDidMount() {
    console.log(new google.maps.DirectionsService());
}
```

gets executed before the API has fully loaded.
I've tried several things to make it work but nothing seems to work:

1. The API can't be loaded using script tags (I don't know if this is due to the specifics of my project) which is why I've used the built-in method `withScriptjs` provided by the package (react-google-maps).
2. I tried to add the API as an external resource (first, I installed the google maps typescript typings and then added the followings lines in the `config.json` file of the project:

Code Snapshot:

[image: code snapshot]

Didn't work.

3. I also tried the react-async-script-loader to load the API but it didn't work either.
4. My latest attempt has been to use Jam3/google-maps-api to get the google.maps Object using a promise once it has been resolved. It failed too.

Maybe,I missed something while trying out these different solutions. As of now, I'm going through each of them once more to be certain I've fully explored any solution.

I'd appreciate some help, thanks!